# Find or detect a single tile from a tiled image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Given a tiled image, is there an algorithm or library like OpenCV or some other python library that can detect the bounds of a single repetition or tile and export it.

***Example***

Given this image

[image]

Detect this seamless single tile from the above image and export it like this

[image]

And this minimum single tile could then be used to recreate the larger pattern.
Furthermore, it would be nice if there was a threshold for quality so it could still detect low-quality jpeg images that may have some artifacts but the larger pattern still recognizable - although this feature isn't too important!

EDIT: I know from repeating patterns that single tiles can be positioned differently and orientated (angled) differently, but so long as it can recreate the overall repeating pattern, so it doesn't have to match or look like my single tile in this example, just as long as it repeats seamless after it is found!

Comment: Is this the only pattern that you are trying to capture? Or should the algorithm generalize across different kinds of patterns?

Comment: It should match any pattern, but the pattern is guaranteed to be repetitive and seamless